# Real analysis solution

Tags: solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that its derivative $f'$ is a continuous function. Moreover, assume that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,$$0\leqslant \vert f'(x)\vert\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$$Define a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by :$$a_1=1~~\text{and}~~a_{n+1}=f(a_n)~\text{for all}~n\in\mathbb{N}$$Prove that there exists a positive real number $M$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,$$\vert a_n\vert \leqslant M$$

---

**My solution**: by integrating as we get $$-x/2 +f(0) \leq f(x) \leq x/2 +f(0)$$ WLOG assume $f(0)=0$, then , then $$ -1/4 \leq f(1)/2 \leq 1/4$$ and $$ -1/8 \leq f(f(1))/2 \leq 1/8$$ and so on... Inductively, we get $$-1/2^n \leq f^n (1)/2 \leq 1/2^n$$. Thus we can set $M=1/2$, which will be the bound.
**My concerns** regarding this proof:

1. Is taking WLOG $f(0)=0$ correct here?
2. The other solutions I saw took the bound to be $M=2|a_2-a_1|+|a_1|$, not what I took.
   Considering my concerns, is this correct?

Comment: No, you cannot assume that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You would need to compare your answer, with $f(x)=g(x)-g(0)$ to the more general function $g(x)$.

Comment: Right, so you it looks like you want to do this without quoting the Banach fixed-point theorem, which would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By Mean Value Theorem $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac 1  2 |a_{n}-a_{n-1}|$. This gives $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac 1 {2^{n-1}}|a_2-a_1|$. This in turn gives $$|a_{n+1}-a_1|$$ $$\le |a_{n+1}-a_n|+|a_n-a_{n-1}|+...+|a_2-a_1|$$ $$\le (\frac  1 2+\frac 1 {2^{2}}+...+\frac  1{2^{n-1}}) |a_2-a_1|$$$$\le |a_2-a_1|.$$

Comment: Is it sufficient to assume $f'(x)<1$, or is the best we can do $f'(x)\leq a < 1$?